# android - How to change the background color of the graph using achartengine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I implemented the Line graph using the achartengine. But i want change the line graph background color. Somebody suggest that the following code for changing the background color.

mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

But it will not change the entire background. I want to change the entire background is it possible? if yes, then how to do it please can anybody help me.The following image is the output of the previous code.I want to change the entire bgcolor(means remaining black color part to white also)[image: Grpah without entire bgcolor]

```
Alinegraph.java
```

public class ALinegraph extends Activity
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
```

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button Linegraph = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Linegraph);
    Linegraph.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Linegraphpage ACTC = new Linegraphpage();
              Intent intent = ACTC.execute(ALinegraph.this);
              startActivity(intent);                  
        }});           
}
```

}

```
Linegraphpage.java
```

public class Linegraphpage extends AbstractDemoChart

{

```
  /**
   * Returns the chart name.
   * 
   * @return the chart name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return "Average temperature";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the chart description.
   * 
   * @return the chart description
   */
  public String getDesc() {
    return "The average temperature in 4 Greek islands (line chart)";
  }

  /**
   * Executes the chart demo.
   * 
   * @param context the context
   * @return the built intent
   */
  public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String[] titles = new String[] { "Crete","Corfu"};
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      x.add(new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
    }
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3 });
    values.add(new double[] { 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 });

    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN};
    PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.CIRCLE,PointStyle.POINT};
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i)).setFillPoints(true);
    }
    setChartSettings(renderer, "", "", "price", 0, 12, 0, 190,
        Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN);
    renderer.setXLabels(10);
    renderer.setYLabels(7);    
    renderer.setShowGrid(false);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });
    renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { -10, 20, -10, 40 });

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, buildDataset(titles, x, values),
        renderer, "");
    return intent;
  }

}
```

***Updated image***

[image]

Comment: can you post image after using  renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: i update the image using ur code.But default color is back so i want to change this color to white. is it possible?

Comment: i think your problem has been solved as you accepted answer. any way i think that should work for complete background

Comment: For **transparent** background, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9314342/1402846).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you should also set your margincolor:

```
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.RED);
```

This will give a whole view of your graph background to red color.

Comment: thanks it's working and more thing how to separate the y-axis labels and text(price) like X-axis also? Please refer the image bottom of the question.

Comment: i think you can use  mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});

Comment: ya its working. Here 30 means distance between y-axis value and text. 15 means distance between x-axis text and symbols. i don't know the values 20 and 0. please can u explain these?

Comment: '20' means using this value u can to reduce the height of the y-axis. "0" means using this value u can to reduce the height of the x-axis.

Comment: one more thing how to move the price in the image to after label 100 in the yaxis.is it possible? if yes, then how to do it

Comment: you can refer [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Chart/achartengine/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.java.java-doc.htm#setMarginsint)

Comment: unfortunately, setting a margin color of transparent results in a color of black ... huh.

Comment: how can i show two color like above the line and below line

Comment: @IssacBalaji I have left working on this graph so long, but I think there is no provision of using different color in same line graph as it is defined once only and the color represents about the same entity that is plotted. May there be any update recently for this in library but I don't think its usual way to plotting the same graph in different color.

Comment: i got solution adding these lines   incomeRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
 incomeRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.graph_shadow)); 
 incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);