# AChartEngine transparent background

Tags: android, background, transparent, achartengine

I have a problem. I'm making a graph with AChartEngine and I would like to have the background of the whole graph to be transparent:

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
(...)
renderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
(...)
GraphicalView g = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, renderer, "dd/MM");
```

But it isn't working properly:

[image]

As you can see, there is a black box appearing behind the x-labels. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
yellos

Comment: hi good designing may i know how you are able to give this gradient effect? and y axis font inside the line?

Comment: How you managed to get y axis labels inside graph. It shows upon y-axis in my app.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));  It looks like there's a bug when setting the color as black transparent

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set transparent background color, you can try:

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
```

It just be work for me!