# AChartEngine set background and margin transparent

Tags: android, android-view, achartengine

I would like to set the background black square to transparent but the result is like this.

```
_renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
_renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
_renderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});
_renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I want to set the graph part a little smaller to have the axis text some space. I don't want the black things... how to set it to be transparent.

Anther question, how to use the xml to set the view. I am now using an linear layout in the xml, and then use linearlayer.addView(view) to add the view that returned by the achartengine: ChartFactory.getBarChartView(...) but if I define a view in the xml, how to directly set the view's content the bar content. I mean not using the dynamic addView in my code, but set the view using xml. Thanks.

[image: my activity view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-> I am not sure if you looked at [AChartEngine transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314342/achartengine-transparent-background?rq=1)  question. It talks about similar issue:

According to it, You can try:

```
setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```

-> If it does not work you may try to create the activity with transparent background and may also give it a dialog look if you want:

[Android: how to create a transparent dialog-themed activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity)

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! it works! But why? why the transparent parameter doesn't work? thanks so much.

Comment: If you read the answer in the link, there seems to be a bug while setting the background as transparent. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set transparent background color, you can try:

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
```

It just be work for me!