# How can I set the margin color from the current theme?

Tags: android, achartengine

After setting the new themes, AChartEngine no longer respects the default background coming from the themes. I made several attempts to resolve this without success. What do I need to do?

Settings from `styles.xml`:

```
res/values/styles.xml: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
res/values-v11/styles.xml: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
```

Part of the Manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Example code:

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setAxesColor(Color.GRAY);
renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
renderer.setChartTitle(label);
renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
renderer.setMargins(new int[] {
        20, 30, 15, 0
});
renderer.setPointSize((float) 5.0);
renderer.setShowGrid(true);
renderer.setXLabels(10);
renderer.setXTitle(getString(R.string.txt_datum));
renderer.setYLabels(10);
renderer.setYTitle(MyPreferenceActivity.getWaehrung());
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.RED
};
PointStyle[] pointStyles = new PointStyle[] {
        PointStyle.POINT
};
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    XYSeriesRenderer tempRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    tempRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
    tempRenderer.setPointStyle(pointStyles[i]);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(tempRenderer);
}

GraphicalView graphicalView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this,
        dataset, renderer, null);

layout.addView(graphicalView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Resulting image.  Where does the incorrect black background come from?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, may be it is a bug, AChartEngine does no longer respect the default background coming from the themes. possible solution is to set margin color.

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
```

see 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7711855/1136010) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9372036/1136010).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably manually set the chart background.

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(color);
```